# Angular and Laravel - Display and save into database based on login and user Id

Tags: angular, laravel, api

I am developing a result management application using Laravel Endpoint and Angular7 Frontend. When I save into the database, I want to save the login/user Id. Also, it will display data based on Login Id. That is, if UserId is 1 (the user is Admin) it will display all the data, but if user Id is any other number apart from 1, it will display the data based on login/user Id in the table

I have developed these table:

1. User: id, username, email, password
2. Exam: id, exam_name, user_id
3. Result: id, exam_id, user_id, score.

Also, I have developed Laravel Endpoint and Angular7 Frontend.

Laravel Endpoint: Controller

```
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->json()->all();

        try
        {
            if(! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials))
            {
                return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 400);
            } else {
                // Generate token from user 
                $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials);
                //return response()->json(compact('token'));
                return response()->json(                [
                    'access_token' => $token,
                    'token_type' => 'bearer'
                ]   );

            }
        }
        catch(JWTException $e)
        {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
        }
    }
```

Exam: Laravel EndPoint

```
    public function index()
    {
        $exams = Exam::all();
        return response()->json($exams);
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'exam_name' => 'required'
        ]);

        $exam = Exam::create($request->all());

        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Great success! New Exam created',
            'exam => $exam
        ]);
    }

    public function show(Exam $exam)
    {
        return $exam;
    }
```

api

```
Route::get('/exams', 'ExamController@index')->name('exams.index');

Route::post('/exams', 'ExamController@store')->name('exams.store');

Route::get('/exams/{exam}', 'ExamController@show')->name('exams.show');
```

Angular: exam.service.ts

```
const apiUrl = "http://localhost/schoolbackend/public/api/exams";

  getExams (): Observable<Exam[]> {
    return this.http.get<Exam[]>(apiUrl)
      .pipe(
        tap(exams => console.log('Fetch exams')),
        catchError(this.handleError('getExams', []))
      );
  }

  addExam (exam): Observable<Exam> {
    return this.http.post<Exam>(apiUrl, exam, httpOptions).pipe(
      tap((exam: Exam) => console.log(`added exam w/ id=${exam._id}`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<Exam>('addExam'))
    );
  }
```

exam-display.component.ts

```
  ngOnInit() {

    this.api.getExams()
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.data = res;
        console.log(this.data);
        this.isLoadingResults = false;
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
        this.isLoadingResults = false;
      });
  }
```

exam-add.component.ts

```
  onFormSubmit(form:NgForm) {
    this.isLoadingResults = true;
    this.api.addExam(form)
      .subscribe(res => {
         // let id = res['_id'];
          this.isLoadingResults = false;
          this.router.navigate(['/examlist']);
        }, (err) => {
          console.log(err);
          this.isLoadingResults = false;
        });
  }
```

When a user logs in:

1. If user_id is 1, then he is an Admin and should be able to view everything in exam-display.ts, else only his exam should be seen (based on his user_id).
2. When a user saves into the database from exam-add.component.ts, his login/user_id should be saved into exam table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first of all, I think you should create a separate column like `is_admin(boolean)` in user table. Directly finding out from id is not a good idea.

1. When you login with Laravel you can take the user object from
   `auth::user()` function.
2. Basis on that result you can check if a user is admin or not.
3. If it is admin you can fetch all the data, otherwise fetch with user_id.
4. Similarly, when storing in exam table you can again get the user from auth.

---

Example:

```
// exam controller

// for fetching exams
public function index()
{
    $userId = auth()->id();

    if ($userId == 1) {
       $exams = Exam::all();
    } else {
       $exams = Exam::where('user_id', $userId)->get(); 
    }

    return response()->json($exams);
}

// for creating new exam
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'exam_name' => 'required'
    ]);

    $exam = new Exam;
    $exam->exam_name = $request->exam_name;
    $exam->user_id = auth()->id()
    $exam->save();

    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Great success! New Exam created',
        'exam => $exam
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Am new in Laravel and Angular. Please can you give a brief sample

Comment: Please don't be offended. I do I relate it with the Angular Frontend

Comment: your angular code looks correct. What seems to be the problem there ?